# IntelliJ IDEA 12.0 Scala worksheet errors under Standard User account but works under Administrator

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, worksheet

When I try to evaluate Scala worksheet in IntelliJ IDEA 12.0 with latest Scala plugin (December 5 2012 version) under Standard User in Windows 7 (32) it says:

```
Cannot start process, the working directory 
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0\bin does not exist
```

The directory really exists.

Evaluating Scala worksheet on the same machine under Administrator account works as expected.

What do I do wrong (besides using Windows)? What can I do to fix the problem (besides using it from Admin account)?

Thank you!

Comment: Proabably easiest to go to Windows Explorer, right click `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0` folder, Properties, select Security tab, click Edit..., select Users, tick "full control" box, OK. Meanwhile you might like to go to the IntelliJ forums and let them know so they can fix it.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I did that but unfortunately that did not have any effect.

Comment: Did you try creating a `bin` directory there?

Comment: `bin` directory does exist in `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0` and everything works fine from under Administrator account.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that IntelliJ IDEA is using the installation directory as the default working directory for Scala worksheets. You can change this setting in the *Run configurations* settings: go to **Run** *>* **Edit configurations...** Once here expand **Defaults** and select **Worksheet**. On the right pane you will see an empty text field named **Working directory**:

[image: Scala worksheet default working directory]

Either enter an existing directory or select one using the button on the right. The directory you specify here will be used for all the worksheets you create. You may also specify a per run configuration working directory if you enter the directory in the corresponding worksheet run configuration instead of in the *Defaults* section.

Answer (score 2):

i have had the same issue with Scala Plugin but the problem is resolved if you use the Edit Configuration to set working directory to current working directory (basically anything other than empty)

this also happens if you do not use external build mode.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously change permission to directory. Do not run any single non-daemon task under Administrator. If similar troubles continue to repeat - consider switching from deprecated OS, to something more stable, to ease your development efforts.

Comment: Hi. Not sure what you mean by "Do not run any single non-daemon task under Administrator". Anyway I changed permissions for the entire IntelliJ IDEA 12.0 to "full control" but that did not help.

Comment: Sometimes permissions does not help, just try run IDEA as Administrator (this considered a bad practice in Unix-es, but ok in Windows - experienced with WebSphere Commerce). That's all I can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the issue http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-5049 to get information when it will be fixed.